# jQuery rewrite href

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, url-rewriting

I have an onclick function that I want to add an anchor to the href value. I do not want to change the URL's, because I need the site to still function for people without javascript / for SEO purposes. so here is what I have tried using (amoung other things):

```
jQuery('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('href', '/#' + jQuery('a'));
});
```

An orginal link looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/PopularTags/
```

URL re-write should look like this, so that AJAX will work:

```
http://www.mysite.com/#PopularTags
```

I was able to get some URL's to work by setting a links name value to the same as the href, but it did not work for links with sub-sections:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Artist/BandName/
```

So not really sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What should the re-write look like for a sub-section link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to use regular expressions, like

```
$('a[rel=ajax]').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace(/\/$/, "");
    return(this.href.replace(/(.*\/)/, "$1#"));
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. It allowed me to keep all the original url's and only the relevant ajax url's changed on click. The end result was like this: "http://www.mysite.com/#PopularTags". Just what I needed. Hope it will work for all my other links. How will this handle a url like this: "http://www.mysite.com/Section1/Section2/"?

Comment: I just realized that if you click a link that is already active, it keeps adding anchors.. So how would I prevent it from adding anchors if one already exist?

Comment: @brandon14_99 Don’t change the `href` attributes every time the link is clicked, only do it once when loading the document. Replace `.click()` with `.each()` and it should work.

Comment: Mathias is correct, replace .click with .each and put it into $(document).ready().

Answer (score 4):

It depends how you code your links in the HTML. If you’re linking to `http://www.mysite.com/PopularTags/` using this:

```
<a href="/PopularTags/">Popular Tags</a>
```

You can simply use this:

```
$(function() {
 $('a[rel=ajax]').each(function() {
  var actualHref = $(this).attr('href');
  this.href = '/#' + actualHref.substring(1, actualHref.length - 1); // cuts off the first and last characters (‘/’)
 });
});
```

This will result in the following HTML:

```
<a href="/#PopularTags">Popular Tags</a>
```

Note that we can set `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`, but we still need the latter to get the actual `href` attribute. `this.href` always holds a full URI, including protocol, domain name, etc — which we don’t want in this example.

Comment: This was a little glitchy if the href didn't not have slashes in front and back of the url, otherwise would have been a good solution.

Comment: @brandon14_99 In your question you say: “An original link looks like this: `http://www.mysite.com/PopularTags/`” So I assumed you’d be consistent across the entire site and code all links like that. If you want flexibility with slashes, use a regular expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('a').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('href','/#'+jQuery(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

will do the job. Read as: At page load, loop through all your links, and replace their href attributes with #{old href}.

Comment: You can set `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`. Native JavaScript ftw! (You’ll still need `$(this).attr('href')` to _get_ the actual `href` attribute, though.)

Comment: This added the "#" symbol, but the orginal link still appeared after. The end result was like this: "http://www.mysite.com/#/PopularTags/"